# Improper alphabetic constant error in title with greek: bug with unicode-math and hyperref in LuaLaTeX

Tags: hyperref, luatex, unicode-math, bugs

Is it a bug of `unicode-math` or `hyperref` in `LuaLaTeX`?

```
    % !TeX program = lualatex                                   
    % !TeX encoding = utf8
    
    \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
    
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}
    \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
    \usepackage{unicode-math} % this one DOES NOT cause error without hyperref
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{hyperref} % this one DOES NOT cause error without unicode-math
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{title $\alpha$}
    
    \end{document}
```

I get an error

> Improper alphabetic constant. \section{title $\alpha$}

Comment: It is a known problem.  Use \texorpdfstring  to add an alternative for the bookmarks.

Comment: Try changing `\section{title $\alpha$}` to `\section{title \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{alpha}}`.

Comment: Pdflatex does not notice the problem, but even with \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{alpha}} does not add alpha in bookmarks.

Comment: If you are using `unicode=math`, compile with xelatex or lualatex. With xelatex, I get bookmarks with α, and `alpha` is the bookmark with `\texorpdfstring`. `\newpage\section{title α1}    
x
\newpage\section{title \textit{α}2}    
x
\newpage\section{title \ensuremath{\mathit{α}}3} 
x
\newpage\section{title \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{alpha}4}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

bookmarks can contain only rather simple text. This means that hyperref has to translate LaTeX input into something that makes sense there. For this it often drops or replace problematic content. In general hyperref is quite good to at least avoid errors in this process, but it can't handle commands which have been let to a char: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/63.
And sadly unicode-math does this in a number of places.

You can use `\texorpdfstring` to offer hyperref an alternative. For example the direct unicode char U+1D6FC would work with most pdf readers. You can input it directly or with the `^^` notation:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}
    \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
    \usepackage{unicode-math} % 
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{hyperref} % 


    \begin{document}

    \section{title \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{ or ^^^^^^01d6fc}}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I believe you've encountered a basic shortcoming in the way pdf bookmarks may be specified, not a shortcoming in either `unicode-math` or `hyperref` *per se*.

The `\texorpdfstring` device may be used to work around this shortcoming. E.g., under LuaLaTeX,

```
\section{title \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{$\symit{alpha}$}}
```

will result in `title alpha` (note: *not* `title α`) showing up in the bookmarks.

*Aside*: Even though slot `x03B1` in the Unicode table points to α and the CMU Serif font has the correct symbol in that slot,

```
\section{title \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{\symbol{"03B1}}}
```

doesn't work at all, as the bookmark now says `title "03B1`. This is definitely far less satisfactory than `title alpha`, isn't it? (This is also why I opined up front that there's a fundamental issue with the way bookmarks can be formed.)

What's the moral of this story? Maybe, it's that one should avoid using math-mode greek letters in the arguments of commands that show up as pdf bookmarks.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to use font commands or the math shift in the `pdf` part of texorpdfstring. You should think in "unicode" there.